# Running Maven Cucumber Test, I'm getting following error No goals have been specified for this build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, cucumber

Im getting below error when I'm running my Cucumber Test, Can you guys please help in resolving the issue.

> You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format `<plugin-prefix>:<goal>` or `<plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>`. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.NoGoalSpecifiedException: No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format `<plugin-prefix>:<goal>` or `<plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>`. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.

Please find my POM.xml below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>MavenFrame</groupId>
  <artifactId>SampleProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>SampleProject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>MyProjectName</projectName>  <!-- Replace with project name -->
                            <outputDirectory>target/cucumber-reports/advanced-reports</outputDirectory>
                            <cucumberOutput>target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json</cucumberOutput>
                            <buildNumber>1</buildNumber>
                            <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
<!--   <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Share how you invoke Maven. What is the exact command you issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just run with following command,

```
mvn verify
```

The error will go off. You can pass any valid goals like test, compile, test-compile, etc. I guess, you are running the mvn command without any parameter. please check the command line syntax.

Answer (score 0):

From your pom, you have specified `<goal>generate</goal>`.

From the error message, it seems this is not a valid `goal`:

"Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy."

So be more specific in what you want to generate: `generate-sources`, `generate-resources`, `generate-test-sources`, or `generate-test-resources`?